# Xcode Test command disabled

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a project that I haven't worked on in almost 2 years, and I've started trying to get it updated and working again with the latest Xcode (7.2.1).

One problem is that the *Product > Test* command is disabled, even though I have a unit test target and I've updated it to use XCTest.

At first none of my tests were listed in the test navigator sidebar, but after deleting my project's folder from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, the tests appeared but they're grayed out. Clearing the DerivedData doesn't seem to have had any other effect.

When I open one of my test source files, the diamonds appear in the gutter next to each test method and I can run the tests by clicking on those. This happened even before clearing DerivedData.

This is with a fresh install of Xcode, on a different computer from when I previously worked on the project.

What else can I do to get Xcode to fully recognize and enable my tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer on the xcode-users mailing list: http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2016/Mar/msg00029.html

The problem is that Xcode stores the test bundle setting for a target in the scheme, and since the scheme wasn't marked as shared, I hadn't added it to the git repository. Re-selecting the test target's bundle (and making the scheme shared and adding it to the repo) fixed the problem.